# Magento2 How to make Thumbnail zoom on click on product page?

Tags: magento2, product-images, product-page, thumbnail, zoom

***Magento2 How to make Thumbnail zoom on click on product page?***

[image: n]

Comment: i want to zoom this small image on click or hover.

Answer (score 0):

*You have to override view.xml file from*

*if you use parent theme* **luma** ***(theme-frontend-luma)***

`vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/etc/view.xml`

*if you use parent theme* **blank** ***(theme-frontend-blank)***

```
vendor/magento/heme-frontend-blank/etc/view.xml
```

*to your theme*

```
app/design/frontend/Package/theme/etc/view.xml
```

*just find*

`<var name="magnifier">`

***and You can do Turn on magnifier (true) "true"***

`<var name="enabled">true</var>`

Comment: not working for me

Comment: php bin/magento cache:clean,
php bin/magento cache:flush also clear browser cache and check again